# Script to set screen resolution by providing X and Y co-ordinates in RedHat

Tags: shell-script, command-line, xrandr, resolution, vncviewer

The goal is to provide resolution X and Y as arguments to the script `./res_set.sh 1920 1080` and `gtf`, `xrandr --newmode` and `--addmode` will be executed according to the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ "$1" == "-h" ]; then
echo "Usage: `basename $0` [X co-ordinate] [Y co-ordinate]"
exit 0
fi

echo "X Co-ordinate";
echo $1;
echo "Y Co-ordinate";
echo $2;
echo "Are you sure? [Y/N]";
read input;
if [ $input == "y" ];
then
gtf $1 $2 60 > kar1.txt                                             #To get modeline
sed -n '3 p' kar1.txt > kar2.txt                                    #Select Line 2
grep -o -E '["_x.0-9 ]+' kar2.txt > kar3.txt                        #Filter result
wo_filter=$(perl -p -e 's/(?:_60.00)//g' kar3.txt | grep "\S");     
filter=$(grep "\S" kar3.txt);
fil_resolution=$(grep -o -P '(?<=").*(?=")' <<< $wo_filter)
resolution=$(grep -o -P '(?<=").*(?=")' kar3.txt)
echo "Filter: $filter";
echo "Wo_filter: $wo_filter";
echo "Resolution: $resolution";
echo "Filted_Resolution: $fil_resolution";
var=$(xrandr --newmode $wo_filter)
xrandr --addmode default $fil_resolution
#rm -v kar*
else
exit;
fi
```

This creates `xrandr --newmode` but fails to add the mode `--addmode` in the resolution list while using this script. I get `xrandr:Cannot find mode`.
But it works and adds to the mode list if `xrandr --newmode` and `--addmode` commands are executed individually.

[image: Input]

[image: Output]

[image: Xrandr output]

This is the output of `xrandr | tail`

My thoughts are :
Are *$variables* are in different datatype and spoiling my result? How will I be able to verify the data type of variables here or in bash (does it matter)?

Comment: Put `echo` before the `xrandr` so we can all see what is actually being called, then edit your question.

Comment: Done @Bib output cannot find the mode